# JavaScript if statement comparison not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The if statement is supposed to compare buttonId value to randButtonId value and even when they do match it still says that it is wrong. The buttons go left to right button1, button2, button3, button4.

```js
setBoard();
var randButtonId;
function setBoard(){
  var r = randomNumber(0 , 235);
  var g = randomNumber(0 , 235);
  var b = randomNumber(0 , 235);
  var color = rgb(r, g, b);
  var r2 = r + 20;
  var g2 = g + 20;
  var b2 = b + 20;
  var diffColor = rgb(r2 , g2 , b2);
  var randButtonId = "button" + randomNumber(1,4);
  setProperty("button1", "background-color", color);
  setProperty("button3", "background-color", color);
  setProperty("button2", "background-color", color);
  setProperty("button4", "background-color", color);
  setProperty(randButtonId, "background-color", diffColor);
  console.log("The correct one is: " + randButtonId);
}

function checkCorrect( buttonId ){
  console.log("Checking: " + buttonId);
  if( buttonId == randButtonId ) {
        console.log("You got it right!");
  } else {
        console.log("WRONG");
  }
  setBoard();
}
onEvent("button1", "click", function() {
  checkCorrect("button1");
});
onEvent("button2", "click", function() {
  checkCorrect("button2");
});
onEvent("button3", "click", function() {
  checkCorrect("button3");
});
onEvent("button4", "click", function() {
  checkCorrect("button4");
});
```

Comment: can you show us the `randomNumber` function? may not be returning what you expect

Comment: There is another error in code snippet.

Comment: it seems that `randButtonId` being defined in the `setBoard` function, the value is undefined when you are in `checkCorrect`. Try to define it outside the function, it should work

Comment: Yea, it looks like your `randomNumber` function might be doing something unexpected.

Comment: Yes, it throws an error stating "randomNumber is not defined", does this code use any JS library.

Answer (score 1):

This probably has to do with lexical scoping. Consider this part of your code:

```js
var randButtonId = 'original value';

function setBoard() {
  // ...
  var randButtonId = 'something'
  console.log({
    randButtonId: randButtonId
  })
  // ...
}

function checkCorrect(buttonId) {
  console.log({
    randButtonId: randButtonId
  })
}

checkCorrect() // { "randButtonId": "original value" }
setBoard() // { "randButtonId": "something" }
checkCorrect() // { "randButtonId": "original value" }
```

You are expecing your functions to use the global variable `randButtonId` declared in the first line. But ´setBoard´ function uses `var` to tell the interpreter that the variable `randButtonId` is scope local.

**TL;DR**: If you want to use the global var `randButtonId` inside `setBoard`, skip the `var` declaration.

However, using global variables is a bad practice as it leads to this kind of problems. A much safer approach it's to encapsulate all your logic within a namespace. For example:

```js
var ButtonChecker = {
  randButtonId: 'original value',
  
  setBoard: function() {
    // ...
    this.randButtonId = 'something'
    console.log({
      randButtonId: this.randButtonId
    })
    // ...
  },

  checkCorrect: function(buttonId) {
    console.log({
      randButtonId: this.randButtonId
    });
  }
};

ButtonChecker.checkCorrect(); // { "randButtonId": "original value" }
ButtonChecker.setBoard(); // { "randButtonId": "something" }
ButtonChecker.checkCorrect(); // { "randButtonId": "something" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not declared randomNumber function

Put this script inside head tag

```
<script>
function randomNumber(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
</script>
```